# move x amount of files to new folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, move, mkdir

I have a folder with 10,000 images, I want to move them all so I have 100 images in each new sub folder. the new folders can be simply named 01,02,03 and so on. how can this be done from the command line in ubuntu? thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest taking a look at for loops in bash as a start, and we can help once there is some code.

Comment: figured it out finally below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

c=1; d=1; mkdir -p folder_${d}

for file in *
do
   if [ $c -eq 100 ]
   then
       d=$(( d + 1 )); c=0; mkdir -p folder_${d}
   fi
   mv "$file" folder_${d}/
   c=$(( c + 1 ))
done
```